# Reading asynchronously from stdin and spawning processes as a result using Twisted

Tags: python, asynchronous, subprocess, twisted, nonblocking

I'm trying to write a module that gets sent data asynchronously from a process using a Pipe (bound to `stdin`), and then needs to spawn and manage processes corresponding to the data received (i.e this will be a callback function).

So I am wondering if Twisted can accomplish these two tasks easily (async reading from stdin, spawning and managing subprocesses) or if there is a better / more elegant solution using some other tool.

Comment: Twisted has ways to do this, as do many other Python libraries (asyncio/trollius, tornado, etc). You could even do this without any async-framework without too much difficulty. As far as which way is the best/most elegant, that's really an opinion-based question, IMO.

Comment: Could you recommend / suggest an elegant and simple one perhaps?

Comment: I have very little experience with Twisted, but it's quite popular. It'll probably suit your needs just fine. If you're using Python 3.4, the `asyncio` module from the standard library can do this in a simple and elegant way, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both task are easy to do in Twisted, and equally important: it has *robust* support across multiple platforms.

Regarding the first task (talking via stdin over a longer time), please see [here](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/process.html).

Regarding the second task (spawning a process, get the output, done): this is essentially a 1 liner in Twisted, please see [here](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/14.0.0/api/twisted.internet.utils.getProcessOutput.html).